# global vars and objects

Tags: solidity

What are the global list of vars and objects available in all contracts ?

I am getting confused with msg object which as msg.sender and tx object with tx.origin ..

And when should I chose which ?

Comment: Regarding your latter question, it would be overkill to answer it here. There's a virtually infinite number of cases when you may need to use a global variable in Solidity. Think about your use case and post another question (more specific) if any.

Answer (score 0):

There's a section in the Solidity docs for this:

[Units and Globally Available Variables](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/units-and-global-variables.html)

For example, `block.timestamp` returns the current Unix timestamp recorded in the Ethereum blockchain.